# Is there an Android library for animated slideshows to show the app's features at launch?

Tags: android

Is there a library that I can use to create an animated slideshow where each slide can display a block of text and an image, the user slides to the right to see all features.

I've seen similar libraries on iOS and many apps on android that do this. Has anyone come across something similar for android?

Comment: Can you link to these iOS libraries?

Comment: https://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/drdynamicslideshow

Comment: ^  This guy never read the part that said: ANDROID.

Comment: http://www.androidviews.net

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you just want a [`ViewPager`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html).  It will let you swipe through Views or Fragments.  If you want a dot indicator or something similar, you can use the [`ViewPagerIndicator`](http://viewpagerindicator.com/) library in addition to your `ViewPager`.

Comment: Thanks, that was almost what I was looking for. I decided to use the ViewPager.onPageScrolled listener to get the positionOffset and animate my views in an interactive method. It looks very similar to the implementation I've seen on other apps.